Proper initialization of injected member with @ApplicationScoped
Consider the following ways of doing Dependency Injection in a pseudo-singleton, by using @ApplicationScoped :
This one will not work:
❌
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService {

    private final Database db;

    @Inject
    public MyService (final Database db) {
        this.db= db;
    } 
...
}

^ That code will crash at startup because the DI engine demands a parameter-less constructor.
This one :
❌
@ApplicationScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class MyService {
    private final Database db;
}

^ ...will crash at startup for the same reasons (missing parameter-less constructor)
I cannot do this :
❌
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private Database db;

}

^ ...because my unit tests need to be able to pass the db's mock explicitly.
So, I try to add the parameter-less constructor:
⚠️
@ApplicationScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class MyService {
    private final Database db;
}

That works, but it makes the linter paranoid : It warns me that db could be null wherever I use it.
I'm aiming at zero warnings. What's the correct way of achieving that?
I've seen some examples where people added a "getInstance" method that checks for null but my intuition is that there is a more straightforward/more compact solution that fits well with the annotations.

What DI engine do you use? Spring allows consturctor injection for at least 10 years

@ЕвгенийРябов could you clarify which of the scenarios above your comment on "constructor injection" would address? I.e. what should it look like with constructor injection?

@ЕвгенийРябов the project doesn't seem to use Spring Boot but I see a log of "javax" so it must be jakarta ?


The first one, you said: DI engine demands a parameter-less constructor, but most of modern di frameworks support that.
Here goes my other question: javax is a more common thing, many of frameworks can use them, so I guess to help we have to know which one do you use


@ЕвгенийРябов I simply don't know how to identify the DI engine being used. Our ApplicationScoped annotation comes from Jakarta. Is Jakarta a DI engine too?

Indeed, there is jakarta ee, but seems it should support constructor injection https://jakarta.ee/specifications/dependency-injection/2.0/apidocs/jakarta/inject/inject

@ЕвгенийРябов in case you believe I'm saying that the fields do not get injected in any of the scenarios, that's not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that the engine demands the parameter-less constructor, which is annoying.

I have "solved" the problem using a workaround, by eliminating the need for the one constructor that needs a parameter (and leaving only the implicit parameter-less constructor).
I couldn't do it before because I needed to manually pass the mock for db, in the unit tests. But Mockito's magic annotation @InjectMock removes the need for that. No manual passing of the mock means to need for an extra constructor means leaving only the default parameter-less constructor means letting the DI engine do its internal magic without interference.
So yeah, not the solution I was looking for but maybe it will help someone in the future.
